# Is there a way to get the content from content controls in a word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-contentcontrol

By utilizing this

```
Application app = new Application();

Document doc = app.Documents.Open(path, ReadOnly: false, Visible: false);

var test = doc.SelectContentControlsByTag("CK");
```

I get each content control with the tag "CK", in my case it's only one.
how do I get the content out of test?

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work by using this:

```
 using (WordprocessingDocument doc =
                    WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, false))
            {

                List<SdtBlock> sdtSubTable = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
                 (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val.Value.Equals(tag)).ToList();

               
                return sdtSubTable[0].SdtContentBlock.InnerText;
            }
```